# How to autowire a Spring Environment object

Tags: java, spring, properties, dependency-injection

I'm attempting to get properties from a .properties file within an object of my application.  My only knowledge of how to do this is via the `Environment` object.

It works great in my configuration...

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {
        "com.production"
})
@PropertySource(value = {
        "classpath:/application.properties",
        "classpath:/environment-${FETTER_ENVIRONMENT}.properties"
})
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.production.repositories")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class Config {
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_URL = "db.url";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_USER = "db.user";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_PASSWORD = "db.password";

    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_DIALECT = "hibernate.dialect";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_FORMAT_SQL = "hibernate.format_sql";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL = "hibernate.show_sql";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_ENTITYMANAGER_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN = "entitymanager.packages.to.scan";

    @Resource
    Environment environment;
```

But I try to do it in another class and it's null.  I've tried using `@Resource` and `@Autowired` and manual injection.

Is there something special about `Environment` that's preventing this?

```
@Component
public class Vendor {
    private String token;

    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;

    public Vendor() {
        //get token from config
        //Environment environment = (Environment) ApplicationContextProvider.getApplicationContext().getBean("environment");
        setToken(environment.getProperty("api.vendor.token"));
    }

    public String getToken() {
        return token;
    }

    public void setToken(String token) {
        this.token = token;
    }
}
```

**Update:** I found [this resource](http://learningviacode.blogspot.com/2012/04/property-files-and-value.html) which highlights the usage of `@Value`, but I don't use any XML configuration in my application.

It looks like this might be what I'm looking for: [Loading properties in Spring 3.1 programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14167332/loading-properties-in-spring-3-1-programmatically)

Comment: I don't think an Environment is relevant in anything other than application context load.

Comment: Is there another way for me to get configuration items from .properties files?

Comment: The `@Value` annotation comes to mind, but you'll have to setup a `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer`. Don't quote me on this, but look it up.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to use [@Value](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Value.html) annotaion for it. But before it is required to declare `<context:property-placeholder` in xml.

See [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/PropertySource.html) for details.

Also, another way:

```
@Inject
ApplicationContext context;
......
Enviroment env = context.getEnvironment();
```

Answer (score 13):

You can use spring `@Autowired` annotation as below, but make sure you annotate your class with `@Component` or similar ones.

```
@Autowired
Environment env;
```

Also make sure your bean is visible for scanning, ie it should be inside `com.production` package in your case.
Component scanning should be enabled like this

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.production"/>
```

or

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.production"} )
```