# what does injecting Environment object help in Spring context?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, dependency-injection

I have come across this code and wondering why Environment `env` is being injected. I do not see any references for it inside the class.

```
public class MyContext implements ServletContextAware {

    @Autowired
    protected Environment env;


  .......

}
```

In the comments of this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15388629/how-to-autowire-a-spring-environment-object), it is mentioned the purpose is to load application context.

shouldn't spring load up the application context during container initialization? how does injecting `Environment` help to load up application context?

Thanks

Comment: in case `MyContext` is defined as Bean, you don't need inject `env`

Comment: it is a bean defined in appconfig