# How to pass JMX parameters to an Spring Application Context

Tags: java, spring

I want to use Spring IoC to wire my services beans.

In some projects, configuration parameters come from properties file.

I'd like to implement this new project with the most similar approach as possible than the other ones so Spring XML application contexts are not aware that now configuration parameters come from a JMX instead of a properties file in the file system.

I'm getting the JMX configuarion parameters from an EJB in JBoss, but I'd really like to implement a server-independent solution that I can use without JBoss or even without EJBs.

Example of what I have in mind:

```
ApplicationContext applicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("/application-context.xml");

applicationContext.replacePropertiesConfigurer( myCustomPropertiesFromJMX );
applicationContext.reloadApplicationContext();

SomeBean aBean = (SomeBean) applicationContext.getBean("someBean");
```

Of course, second and third line are invalid, but they're the way I imagine my desired solution.

Kind regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Spring 3.1.x you just have to implement [PropertySource](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/env/PropertySource.html) that will get properties from wherever you want. And then add it to your application environment:

```
ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext
        = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("/application-context.xml");

PropertySource myPropertySource = new SomeImplementationOfPropertySource();
applicationContext.getEnvironment().getPropertySources().addFirst(myPropertySource);
```

I hope that I get your question right.

Comment: :O... I'll test it and let you know as soon as I'm able to. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to [Errandir](https://stackoverflow.com/users/274205/errandir) for the guidance.

Thanks to [Evgeniy Dorofeev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1831293/evgeniy-dorofeev) too for his response in another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14167332/loading-properties-in-spring-3-1-programmatically) that asked the same.

The final code that suits my needs is next:

Create the context without factorying Spring beans yet (**false** constructor's second parameter):

```
ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(new String[]{"classpath:main-applicationContext.xml"}, false);
```

Create the properties wherever they come from:

```
Properties jmxConfig = new Properties();
jmxConfig.setProperty("parameterX", valueX);
```

Create programatically a PropertiesPlaceholderConfigurer and bind the previous custom properties we just created and bind it to the application context:

```
PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer mapPropertySource = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
mapPropertySource.setProperties(jmxConfig);
applicationContext.addBeanFactoryPostProcessor(mapPropertySource);
```

Finally, it's configured and now it's fine to create instances and get them:

```
applicationContext.refresh();

MyService myService = applicationContext.getBean("myService", MyService.class);
```

Comment: To really be able to refresh the context I had to create a new one if someone was loaded previously, by first closing the previous one and recreating it. Since addBeanFactoryPostProcessor seems not to be overriding the previous configuration.