# aws lambda function with spring autowired dependencies

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

when code is executed in amazon aws lambda, my @autowired spring dependencies are null.  Makes sense if there is no context being loaded, but i thought SpringBeanAutowiringSupport would help.  How do you inject dependencies correctly in amazon lambda?

This is my code that has null autowired fields but otherwise works fine (if i replace autowired with new:

```
@Component
public class ApplicationEventHandler {

@Autowired
private Foo foo;


         public ApplicationEventHandler() {
             logger.info("I'm sure the constructor is being called");
            SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.processInjectionBasedOnCurrentContext(this);
             //doesn't seem to help
         }

         public void deliveryFailedPermanentlyHandler(SNSEvent event, Context context) throws IOException {
             foo.doStuff() // causes NPE

         }
```

thanks in advance!

Comment: Here is a simple way with no "magic" involved: [Just Spring-enabled AWS Lambdas](https://www.profit4cloud.nl/blog/just-spring-enabled-aws-lambdas/)

Comment: I've just tested what Attila T is saying, and it worked. Thx mate!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this project on github provides a template for what i'm trying to do which works fine:

https://github.com/cagataygurturk/aws-lambda-java-boilerplate

Comment: Hi! I recommend to see also this framework: https://github.com/lambadaframework/lambadaframework

Comment: I think it makes sense that AWS lamda isn't executing your code like a spring aware servlet container would, so there is no application context and dependency injection doesn't happen.  Lambas are supposed to be small units of work anyway, so if you needed a more complex application the lambda function should call a webservice running on another platform.

Comment: In Spring, your class is initiated by Spring itself and then all DI annotations are scanned to provide dependencies. AWS Runtime does not do such a thing, that's why annotations are not evaluated.

Comment: The boilerplate in the repo from @ÇağatayGürtürk  works for the most part, but it doesn't resolve the Value's from the properties files. I tried using the solution here but it seems like the properties file is getting read (if I change the file name it fails) but the Values are missing. https://stackoverflow.com/a/14168026

Answer (score 2):

[AWS Lambda Best Practices notes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/best-practices.html) talks about DI:

> **Minimize the complexity of your dependencies.** Prefer simpler
>   frameworks that load quickly on [Execution Context](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/running-lambda-code.html) startup. For
>   example, prefer simpler Java dependency injection (IoC) frameworks
>   like [Dagger](http://square.github.io/dagger/) or [Guice](https://github.com/google/guice), over more complex ones like [Spring Framework](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework).

So I'd like to suggest you to use [Dagger 2](https://github.com/google/dagger) (because Square's Dagger 1.x is already deprecated). It provides such benefits:

- light-weight framework with very few integrations, Java interface/annotation configuration and compile-time code generated bindings;
- very small size;
- fail as early as possible ( compile-time, not runtime);
- performance - as fast as hand-written code and no coding around the framework.