# AWS Lambda - Spring @Autowire

Tags: spring-boot, aws-lambda

I developed a project using RestController in Spring Boot and it worked without error.

Now I use AWS lambda but I get a null pointer exception when I try to inject a Spring bean to the the lambda handler:

```java
public class HelloWorldHandler implements RequestHandler<Map<String, Object>, Object> {

  @Autowired
  private IUserService userservice;

  public Object handleRequest(Map<String, Object> input, final Context context) {

    Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
    headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json");

    User testUser = new User();
    testUser.setId("10");
    testUser.setLastname("test_lastname");
    testUser.setMail("test@al.com");

    userservice.addUser(testUser);

    return new GatewayResponse("success", headers, 200);
  }
}
```

Exception:

```json
{
  "errorMessage": "java.lang.NullPointerException",
  "errorType": "java.lang.NullPointerException",
  "stackTrace": [
    "HelloWorldHandler.handleRequest(HelloWorldHandler.java:30)",
    "HelloWorldHandler.handleRequest(HelloWorldHandler.java:21)"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Please include the full stack trace.

Comment: @OrtomalaLokni 
  START RequestId: 2b718de0-5999-11e7-8a84-1d1d4d448537 Version: $LATEST
java.lang.NullPointerException: java.lang.NullPointerException
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.aws.codestar.projecttemplates.handler.HelloWorldHandler.handleRequest(HelloWorldHandler.java:29)
 at com.aws.codestar.projecttemplates.handler.HelloWorldHandler.handleRequest(HelloWorldHandler.java:23)

END RequestId: 2b718de0-5999-11e7-8a84-1d1d4d448537
REPORT RequestId: 2b718de0-5999-11e7-8a84-1d1d4d448537 Duration: 2613.73 ms Billed Duration: 2700 ms  Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 47 MB

Comment: Please edit your question and add the exception to it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [amazon aws lamba function with spring autowired dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35753573/amazon-aws-lamba-function-with-spring-autowired-dependencies)

Answer (score 0):

HelloWorldHandler is not a Spring component so you can't just inject a bean to that class. Spring context is not loaded even. So it can't work :)

You can use Spring Cloud Function to run context and get access to all Spring feature including "Autowired".

Or you can try this one: https://github.com/MelonProjectCom/lambda-http-router

Easy to use and allows to run multiple handlers in single lambda:

```java
    @PathPostMapping("/example/test")
    public String example(@Body String body) {
        return "Hello World! - body: " + body;
    }
```